# Sudo apt-get update not working

Tags: ubuntu, apt, repository

How do I go back to the beginning? To ground zero of installation for Ubuntu? Or how do I fix this problem?

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for charlesbenjamin: 
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu bionic Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu bionic Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Answer (score 1):

The PPA is not being found; remove it or disable from software sources. If you open software sources, switch to the other tab then find the lines containing "http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins" you can untick to disable or select and delete to remove.

Full details on usage here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu